# Modify CSS using jQuery without using IDs or Classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML code:

```
    <span id="one">one</span>
    <div>
        <span>two</span>
    </div>


  <span id="click">click</span>


$("#click").click(function(){
    $(this).css('color', 'red');
})
```

I would like to be able to change the color of

```
<span>two</span>
```

when I click the "click" span but without adding any custom CSS class or id attribute using jQuery.

Comment: Why can't you edit the markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    $("div>span").css('color', 'red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rwddN/2/

OR

you can use [`:contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/)

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    $("span:contains(two)").css('color', 'red');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rwddN/12/

Answer (score 5):

In the exact case you describe, you can color that span with this selector:

```
$('#one').next('div').find('span').css('color','red');
```

Or as pimvdb pointed out:

```
$('#one + div span').css('color','red');
```

`+` does the same as `next()` and this also eliminates having to use `.find()`.

Comment: +1 You could also combine this: `$('#one + div span').css('color','red');`

Comment: Nice, I wasn't aware of the `+` symbol in selectors :)

Answer (score 2):

If your HTML is exactly as shown in the question then you can do this:

```
$("#click").click(function(){
    $("#one").next().find("span").css("color", "red");
});
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/pd5nB/). This works by getting the `span` with `id` "one", then getting the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) element (which is the `div`) and finally finding the `span` within that `div`.